# Electric field calculations VASP

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, electronic-structure

Does anybody have experience in electric field calculations using VASP? I gave the electric field to an already relaxed structure and it shows `electronic self consistency is not achieved`. I even tried `NELM=300` but still the ground state energy has not been converged.

If I use the `ISIF` tag along with the electric field tag, the calculations end abruptly and show an error. Is there anything else we can do? Would it be right if I take the `CONTCAR` after giving the electric field and relax it again using `ISIF` tags?

Comment: I tried some. I also find for many cases, jobs do not get convergent. The electric field might show the vivid change for some perfect structures but somehow does not show any effect on their defect structures. I think dipole correction may be problematic. VASP admin wrote it is possible for relaxation https://www.vasp.at/forum/viewtopic.php?t=17390. You may post a question in the VASP forum.

Comment: Thanks @BinhThien. I used only EFIELD, LDIPOL and IDIPOL tags. How to choose the value of DIPOL and EFIELD_PEAD? I am trying to find the effect of electric field on a 2D metallic structure. As you said, i will also try posting it in the forum

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but just came today to check how things are going? Did you figure out the answer? Are you still working on this? Let us know! By the way, can you include your entire input and output files in `code` blocks please?